# Load testing: Choosing between a tool or simulating clients on my own for this scenario?

Tags: testing, video-streaming, jmeter, load-testing, pusher

I want to load test my application and I'm deciding b/w choosing a load testing service or simulating the clients on my own.

My question is whether I can accomplish this user scenario using *any* of the load testing tools available.

My test will have two types of users, A & B. Communication would be between A and B. A-A communication and B-B communication is not there.

1. I want Users to login to my application through mobile or web. Either type of users could log in through either type of platform.
2. Make multiple GET/PUT/POST requests to my application server with specific parameters.
3. Be able to exchange video or text messages by integrating through services like Pusher and Vidyo.

'3' is probably the most important requirement for me, and I'm wondering if I could simulate the dummy users so that it listens to a pusher channel and can open up a Vidyo iframe in the emulated browser / mobile device for a specific pusher message?

Answer (score 0):

I got on call with Blazemeter and turns out they or anyone in the market doesn't support plugins on emulated browsers. I finally simulated the clients on my own replicating all the server calls a typical browser or mobile device makes for my application.

I haven't yet been able to load test Vidyo and don't know if there's a way to do it except by opening up conferences manually.

I was able to load test services like Pusher and SQS successfully.